# Can you carry over add-on feed settings when duplicating a Gravity Form?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, user-registration, gravityforms, campaign-monitor

So I know when you duplicate a gravity form it carries over the settings that are there by default like notification and confirmations.

But I was wondering if its possible carryover add-on settings when duplicating a Gravity Form like Campaign Monitor settings and User Registration settings.

The only reason I ask is that I need to make over 100 forms which are all basically the exact same apart from one little thing that is different on all of them and it's becoming a very very long process having to set up the Campaign Monitor settings and User Registration settings on every single form.

Hope there is a work around this!

Comment: Did you consider duplicating the database entries with a custom SQL query?

Comment: @jasie I didn't but what I need to do is basically duplicate some of the addons feeds on my form I know I have to use this function https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_post_form_duplicated/ I just don't know where to start really, any ideas?

Comment: @IbrarrKhan do you really need over 100 forms just to change one little thing, or can you use one form with conditional logic?

Comment: @Naomi Nope they all need to be different forms because they are for whitepapers and they all have to have different form notifications

Comment: @IbrarrKhan form notifications use conditional logic, too. You can create multiple notifications and set conditional logic on each. Or, you can have one notification and set conditional logic on the recipient or [in the message itself](https://gravityplus.pro/how-to/setup-gravity-forms-conditional-confirmation-or-notification-messages-based-on-submitted-values/).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: My answer does not match the changed question, anymore. It may still work, though - it depends on how the GF add-ons save their settings. Possibly, those are duplicated as well.

The gravity forms docu gives this answer on 'Duplicating Forms':

```
wp gf form duplicate
```

See https://docs.gravityforms.com/managing-forms-wp-cli/#duplicating-forms

To duplicate the form with the ID 5, you do:

```
wp gf form duplicate 5
```

Use the WP-CLI to execute the duplicate command: https://wp-cli.org/

You did not share specifics about the little changes that you need per form, so I can not address this in my answer.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, so doing it this way will duplicate all the add on feeds attached to the form? because that's the only problem I am having at the moment.

Comment: Why don't you just test it for one forms to find out what this gets you? Your question does not contain any specifics, so I can't answer that, sorry. Which add-ons do you mean? Please add an example of an add-on setting to your question

Comment: For these forms i need to duplicate a campaign monitor feed and a user registration feed for every form

Comment: There is a plugin which does a feeds copy: https://anvilzephyr.com/product/copy-feeds-plugin-gravity-forms/

Comment: You might also find useful code in this (outdated) free plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/importexport-add-on-feeds-for-gravity-forms/

Comment: I have found this https://docs.gravityforms.com/feed-object/ but not sure if i can do it like this?

Comment: Respectfull, I will not continue trying to help you find a solution as it seems you are not trying any of the proposed approaches. If you want someone to solve this for you, please hire someone or collect points and offer a bounty.